# In VMware Workstation is there a way for a Kali Linux virtual machine to be able to sniff packets with the wireless NIC?

Tags: vmware-workstation, kali-linux

I'm new to Kali Linux.

I'm running Kali Linux inside VMware Workstation.

I have a Ralink USB wireless NIC connected to my PC.

I want to enable Monitor mode which is simply done with the *airmon-ng start wlan0* command. But there's no wlan0 adapter to be found. When I enter the *ifconfig* command I only see eth0 and lo:

[image: SCREENSHOT]

Comment: comon guys, anyone?

Comment: You can connect your USB WiFi adapter to your VM. It should be picked up and you should be able to use it.

Comment: How do you connect the USB wifi directly to a VM? Isn't the VM seperated from the physical adapter by a virtual adapter and a virtual switch?

Comment: On the very bottom of the screen you have a list of (virtual) devices. Devices like USB mass storage, phones, headsets etc can be connected to the VM (and disconnected from the host) by right clicking them and clicking on `Connect (disconnect from host)`

Comment: You mean the bottom right? There is no such option. If I right click on the Network Adapter icon there's only a "Connect" option, without the "disconnect from Host" part. And if I go into its settings the only options are to choose between Bridged, Host-only, and NAT, all of which do not disconnect it from the Host.

Comment: Yes, there should be your network card. If you have it connected via USB3, try changing to a USB 2.0 port. Also make sure you have installed `open-vm-tools` (the successor to VMWare guest tools).

Comment: I switched it to a USB 2.0 port, made no difference. There's still no "disconnect from host" option. And VMware tools is installed.

Comment: That doesn't seem to apply to VMware workstation

Answer (score 0):

There are two possibilities:

1. Wireless card not connected with Virtual Machine

   If this is the case then you can fix issue by connecting wireless card to virtual machine.

   Go to VM > Removable devices > (wireless card name/number) > **Connect (Disconnect from Host)**
2. Compatible driver not found (very less chance for your case but maybe)

   In this case you have to find proper driver for your wireless adapter.

Answer (score 0):

You can bypass that wireless adapter usb to the vm. You just need to plugin the wireless usb, start the vm, and go to settings in vm > removable devices > chose the wireless usb > connect